# Postgres where clause over two columns from subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, subquery, where-clause

- Database: Postgres
- Table name: `records`
- Has 4 columns `Year | Dept | Expense | Month`

So per year there can be up to one record for each month / per department.

I have a sub-query which returns me the below data based on constraints.

```
Year | Dept
2001 | HR
2001 | ACC
2001 | TECH
2002 | TECH
2003 | HOUSE-KEEPING
2003 | TECH
```

Now I need to run another query on the same table to get a total of the expenses for each value pair.

Using the output of the subquery, my main query will be something like

```
select Dept, sum(Expense) 
from records 
where (Year, Dept) in (...)
... I want to iterate over value pairs from the subquery

(SUBQUERY which returns
Year | Dept
2001 | HR
2001 | ACC
2002 | TECH
2003 | HOUSE-KEEPING
)
```

When I run this select statement, the output returned is only containing data for TECH across all three years.

Please can help understand how I can run the main select over all the rows of the subquery

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Refactor the subquery to a join.

Say you have

```
SELECT a, b FROM t1 WHERE (x,y) IN (SELECT x1, y1 FROM t2 WHERE ...)
```

which won't work. You rewrite to

```
SELECT a, b
FROM t1
INNER JOIN (
   -- subquery here:
   SELECT x1, y1
   FROM t2
   WHERE ...
) AS some_alias
WHERE t1.x = some_alias.x1
  AND t1.y = some_alias.y1;
```

Note, [in PostgreSQL you shouldn't use a CTE (WITH query) for this](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-ctes-are-optimization-fences/).

You can abbreviate

```
WHERE t1.x = some_alias.x1
  AND t1.y = some_alias.y1;
```

to

```
WHERE (x, y) = (x1, y1)
```

though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply Craig. This will get me started. I should have provided more details in the initial question. My subquery is formed using a with query. I had simplified the actual database in hope of simplifying the answering part. Your answer has made me realize it wasn't a great idea. I am going to post a new question with all the details. 

Thanks a lot for your help again.

Comment: Hi Craig - I have re-posted the question with all the details here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46425141/postgres-where-clause-over-two-columns

Comment: Doesn't the `inner join` need an `on`?

Comment: @Growler Yeah. I think it should've been `ON` not `WHERE`. Don't remember anymore, no time to re-check.

Comment: @Craig didn't mean to nitpick- I thought perhaps this was some hidden postgres trickery I didn't know about

Comment: @Growler Totally fine. That's what comments are for. If it gave you pause, it confused someone else too.

Answer (score 7):

Solution [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29112924/1431079):

```
SELECT dept, SUM(expense) FROM records 
WHERE ROW(year, dept) IN (SELECT x, y FROM otherTable)
GROUP BY dept;
```

The [ROW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) function does the magic.

Comment: @Thirumal Which version of Postgresql are you using? I use 9.6 & 10.7 and it's working fine. This exact sample may not work as it's missing group by and maybe details corresponding to your own table structure but the principle is there.

Answer (score 7):

Now in 2022 you can straight up do this:

```
SELECT dept, SUM(expense) FROM records 
WHERE (year, dept) IN (SELECT year, dept FROM otherTable);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't got millions of rows, you can keep the semantic of your query by concatenating the values into one value:

```
select Dept, sum(Expense)
from records
where Year || Dept in (select Year || Dept from ...)
```

It's easy to read, understand and maintain, and it will perform just fine unless you have zillions of years and departments, which seems highly unlikely.