# Postgres where clause over two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, where-clause

Database - I am working on in Postgres 9.6.5

I am analyzing the data from US Airport Authority (RITA) about the flights arrival and departures. 
This link (http://stat-computing.org/dataexpo/2009/the-data.html) lists all the columns in the table.

The table has following 29 columns

> No  Name   Description
>
> 1  Year    1987-2008
>
> 2  Month   1-12
>
> 3  DayofMonth  1-31
>
> 4  DayOfWeek   1 (Monday) - 7 (Sunday)
>
> 5  DepTime     actual departure time (local, hhmm)
>
> 6  CRSDepTime  scheduled departure time (local, hhmm)
>
> 7  ArrTime     actual arrival time (local, hhmm)
>
> 8  CRSArrTime  scheduled arrival time (local, hhmm)
>
> 9  UniqueCarrier   unique carrier code
>
> 10     FlightNum   flight number
>
> 11     TailNum     plane tail number
>
> 12     ActualElapsedTime   in minutes
>
> 13     CRSElapsedTime  in minutes
>
> 14     AirTime     in minutes
>
> 15     ArrDelay    arrival delay, in minutes
>
> 16     DepDelay    departure delay, in minutes
>
> 17     Origin  origin IATA airport code
>
> 18     Dest    destination IATA airport code
>
> 19     Distance    in miles
>
> 20     TaxiIn  taxi in time, in minutes
>
> 21     TaxiOut     taxi out time in minutes
>
> 22     Cancelled   was the flight cancelled?
>
> 23     CancellationCode    reason for cancellation (A = carrier, B = weather, C = NAS, D = security)
>
> 24     Diverted    1 = yes, 0 = no
>
> 25     CarrierDelay    in minutes
>
> 26     WeatherDelay    in minutes
>
> 27     NASDelay    in minutes
>
> 28     SecurityDelay   in minutes
>
> 29  LateAircraftDelay   in minutes

There are about a million rows for each year.

I am trying to find out a count the most busy airports when delay is more than 15minutes. 
column DepDelay - has the delay time. 
origin - is the origin code for the airport.

All the data has been loaded into a table called 'ontime'

I am forming the query as follows in stages.

1. select airports where delay is more than 15 minutes

   select origin,year,count(*) as depdelay_count from ontime 
       where 
       depdelay > 15
       group by year,origin 
       order by depdelay_count desc 
       )
2. Now I wish to pull out only the top 10 airports per year - which I am doing as follows

   select x.origin,x.year from (with subquery as (
       select origin,year,count(*) as depdelay_count from ontime 
       where 
       depdelay > 15
       group by year,origin 
       order by depdelay_count desc 
       )
       select origin,year,rank() over (partition by year order by depdelay_count desc) as rank from subquery) x where x.rank <= 10;
3. Now that I have the top 10 airports by depdelay - I wish to get a count of the total flights out of these airports.

   select origin,count(*) from ontime where origin in 
       (select x.origin from (with subquery as (
           select origin,year,count(*) as depdelay_count from ontime 
           where 
           depdelay > 15
           group by year,origin 
           order by depdelay_count desc 
           )
           select origin,year,rank() over (partition by year order by depdelay_count desc) as rank from subquery) x where x.rank <= 2)
           group by origin
           order by origin;

If I modify the Step 3 query by adding the year in the year clause

---- will be any value from (1987 to 2008)

```
select origin,count(*) from ontime where year = (<YEAR>) origin in  
(select x.origin from (with subquery as (
    select origin,year,count(*) as depdelay_count from ontime 
    where 
    depdelay > 15
    group by year,origin 
    order by depdelay_count desc 
    )
    select origin,year,rank() over (partition by year order by depdelay_count desc) as rank from subquery) x where x.rank <= 2)
    group by origin
    order by origin;
```

But I have to do this manually for all years from 1987 to 2008 which I want to avoid.

Please can you help refine the query so that I can select the data for all the years without having to select each year manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find CTEs int he middle of queries to e confusing.  You can basically do this with one CTE/subquery:

```
with oy as (
      select origin, year, count(*) as numflights,
             sum( (depdelay > 15)::int ) as depdelay_count,
             row_number() over (partition by year order by sum( (depdelay > 15)::int ) desc) as seqnum
      from ontime
      group by origin, year
     ) 
select oy.*
from oy
where seqnum <= 10;
```

Note the use of conditional aggregation and using window functions with aggregation functions.

Comment: Hi Gordon - thanks for the reply, I agree that the CTEs in the middle are confusing. I was building the query in stages so I worked with the CTE as is.
Your query gives a syntax error at 


flightdata_info-> where seqnum <= 10;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "sum"
LINE 3:              sum( (depdelay > 15)::int ) as depdelay_count,
                     ^
flightdata_info=>


In the meantime, I am looking at the query to understand how its written and work out what the error points to

Comment: There is a missing comma after `numflights`

Comment: Yes, added the comma and works seamlessly. Thanks a ton.